# Scrapy : Unable to extract attribute field using css selector

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, css-selectors

Here is the HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<div class="container" id="content-area">
    <div class="flex-row flex-baseline flex-space-between" data-id="1826" id="info">
      <h1 class="no-margin">XYZ</h1>
        <div class="new-stack" id="sublists">Added</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am looking to pull the `data-id` attribute inside `div` tag. Here is what I am trying using CSS Selector

```
>>> response.css("#content-area div")[0].css("::attr[data-id]").get()
```

And I got below error

```
cssselect.parser.SelectorSyntaxError: Got pseudo-element ::attr not at the end of a selector
```

Here is how I solved it by combining CSS and XPATH Selectors.

```
>>> response.css("#content-area div")[0].xpath("@data-id").get()
'1826'
```

Is there any solution which can do this using just CSS Selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `()` instead of `[]`

```py
>>> response.css("#content-area div")[0].css("::attr(data-id)").get()
```